# Can anyone please let me know how to implement the differential timer concept

Tags: c, timer

Can anyone please let me know how to implement the differential timer concept.

I am working on a mobile platform, which gives or upports only one hardware timer. Using this i have to maintain different timers requested by application.

Can anyone please suggest a best approach to implement this software timers using one hardware timer

Comment: Differential timer?  What do you mean exactly?

Comment: What do you mean with *timer*?

Answer (score 2):

Did I understand your question correctly as “I have only one hardware timer, but my application needs several timers, one slow, one fast, some others”?

Then you can probably do it like this:

```
typedef void (*timer_callback_fn)(void *);

// private
struct registered_timer {
  timer_callback_fn callback;
  void *data;
  unsigned long ticks; // hardware ticks between calls to this timer
};

void timer_register(timer_callback_fn cb, unsigned long ticks) {
  ...
}

static void interrupt on_hardware_timer(void) {
  static unsigned long ticks = 0;

  ... for each registered timer ...
  if (ticks % timer->ticks == 0) {
    timer->callback(timer->data);
  }
}
```

Of course, you have to be careful that all your software timers must be able to be processed within one tick of the hardware timer.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand what you're trying to achieve, you basically have a single timer and you want to be able to simulate having multiple timers?  That's really easy then.

For each "timer", get the current time from your real timer.  This will act as the base time for the timer.  When you want to get the time elapsed, get the current time (from your real timer) and find the difference between the current time and the base time.  It's as simple as that.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly:

Keep a sorted list of "virtual" timers, with the one with least reamaining time first. The "real" timer is then set to the time of that timer. When the real timer expires, process the first virtual timer, remove it from the list, and set your real timer to the same time as the (new) first virtual timer.

If you have a large number of virtual timers, you may want to consider another data structure than a simple sorted list.

But I'm not sure that's what you're asking.